# Angular 2 Routing: How to change the Id

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

i am building angular 2 with routing.

app.routing.module.ts

```
  { path: '', component: CComponent },
  { path: 'Ddata:id', component: DComponent, 
    children: [
        {
        path: 'qdata:id',
        component: QComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'Adata', component: AComponent },

]
```

When i click on that i am getting data by passing the Id to fetch the data, the Url looks like [http://localhost:4200/Ddata/1](http://localhost:4200/Ddata/1.)

i want modify this url to http://localhost:4200/Ddata/name

please help me

Comment: How does DComponent look like? Please provide a reproducible stackblitz example

Comment: @Pramod what do you mean by name? is a parameter or just a routing path?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha it is parameter

Answer (score 1):

You want route masking, but the only way to achieve this is to have the backend accept the name instead of id.

If you cannot change your backend, you could also use matrix params. The urls would look like this: `http://localhost:4200/Ddata/name;id=1`. It would be a little cleaner for users and you could still read the id from activated route's params.

Read more about matrix params in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero)